# Entorno para manipular datos de MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estimados.
Necesito proporcionar a un usuario final, que no conoce la sintaxis de SQL, una manera simple para que actualice y filtre datos de una base MySQL. 
Conocen alguna herramienta que facilite esto? O algo que se pueda integrar con la base para hacer consultas sencillas, aplicar filtros y modificar datos? 
El objetivo principal es que el usuario no tenga que consultar y extraer información a través de código sql.
Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Estpa pregunta es muy extensa OP, aquí se resuelven dudas específicas, no algo tan general. Sí no cambias esto, posiblemente tu pregunta sea cerrada por ser muy extensa o por que está basada en opiniones personales

Comment: Gracias !! Cómo sugieres que formule la pregunta frente a la necesidad que tengo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A través de PHP le puedes crear un programa a través del cual sea posible acceder a la BD y **crear, leer, actualizar, borrar** (CRUD) ... lo que quiera. Él cliente accedería a dicho programa PHP y tú programarías todas las consultas de forma totalmente transparente.

Si la BD está alojada en un servidor puedes crear perfectamente privilegios de acceso a tu aplicación y a la carpeta donde estará alojado el programa PHP, protegerla por contraseña a través de .htaccess, etc.